# Acknowledge when the client has completely processed the message. Rabbitmq

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, consumer

```cs
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received +=  (model, ea) =>
{
    var eventName = ea.RoutingKey;
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);
              
    ProcessEvent(eventName, message);
    channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
};

channel.BasicConsume(queue: _queueName,
    autoAck: false,
    consumer: consumer);
```

```cs
 private void ProcessEvent(string eventName, string message)`
 {
 //code send the acknowledgement here, before completing the processing
   if (_subsManager.HasSubscriptionsForEvent(eventName)`
   {
    using (var scope = _autofac.BeginLifetimeScope(AUTOFAC_SCOPE_NAME))`
     {
      var subscriptions = _subsManager.GetHandlersForEvent(eventName);`
        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)`
          {
             if (subscription.IsDynamic)`
        { 
          var handler = scope.ResolveOptional(subscription.HandlerType) as IDynamicIntegrationEventHandler;
          dynamic eventData = JObject.Parse(message);`
            handler.Handle(eventData);                         
        }
```

I need to acknowledge when the client has completely processed the message using RabbitMQ.  In my application, acknowledgement comes once consumer constructor is called. I want it to be done only after processing is finished.   I have created a common class for message Broker. but I want this functionality for a particular subscribe event. Here is my code, I am processing the event**

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#consuming) shows us how to do this:

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    // ... process the message

                    // ACK the message
                    channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                };
String consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
```

See also https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Comment: hi..I did same, but it sends back the acknowledgement immediately the constructor is called in the class while process the message .Acknowledment comes before the channel.basicAck function..while proceesing is not completed.I want it should be only after the processing finished.Because I am updating the 2 databases

Comment: Please edit your question and show as the relevant part of your code.